# How to write checkbox active record search using using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How to do checkbox search through scope in ruby

i have form like this

```
<% VenueCategory.all.each do |c| %>
 <%= check_box_tag("venue_categories[]", c.id)%>
 <%= c.name%>
<% end %>`
```

i want to search venue categories if more than one option is selected. How to do it with scope

i tried like this
in my `property.rb` model

`scope :venue_category, -> (venue_categories_id) { where venue_category_ids: venue_categories }`

**controller:**

`@properties = Property.where(:status=>'1')
    @properties = @properties.venue_categories(params[:venue_categories]) if params[:venue_categories].present?`

model venuecategory.rb

`class VenueCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property
end`

property.rb

`class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :venue_categories
end`

i'm getting error when i tried this.

I don't know how to do multiple checkbox options search with scope. Please help me if anyone knows.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Anthony E  undefined method `venue_categories' for #<Property::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f79e6c17ea8>

Comment: now i changed controller like this `@properties = @properties.venue_category if params[:venue_categories].present?` then  i'm getting this error in my property model 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'

Comment: when i select more than one venue categories from the list ,i'm getting params like this 'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","venue_categories"=>["1", "3", "4", "7", "8", "9"]}.

Comment: how i will search if i select more than one options

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Think of scope as a function with name `venue_categories` which accepts a parameter - `venue_categories` - an array of venue category ids.

```
scope :venue_categories, -> (venue_categories) { where(id: venue_categories) }
```

Here `id` is the field name to be matched.

**Controller**

```
@properties = Property.where(status: '1')
@properties = @properties.venue_categories(params[:venue_categories]) if params[:venue_categories].present?
```

This should work.

Comment: @Senbin for this it is getting query like this. ' SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE `properties`.`status` = '1' AND `properties`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8)'

Comment: @sree Sorry, I am not clear on how you want it. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: instead of getting properties.ids in i need venue_categories`.`id` IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8)

Comment: this is the query i supposed to get. SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` INNER JOIN `properties_venue_categories` ON `properties_venue_categories`.`property_id` = `properties`.`id` INNER JOIN `venue_categories` ON `venue_categories`.`id` = `properties_venue_categories`.`venue_category_id` WHERE `properties`.`status` = '1' AND `venue_categories`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8)

Comment: So you want to fetch properties that having the specified venue_category ids?

Comment: Can you update the question to indicate the relationship among properties, properties_venue_categories and venue_categories?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110201/discussion-between-sebin-and-sree).

Comment: Sebin i updated my relationship. also in table properties_venue_categories , i have columns like property_id and venue_category_id.

Comment: Can you try something like `scope :venue_categories, -> (venue_categories) { joins(:properties_venue_categories).where(properties_venue_categories: {venue_category_id: venue_categories})`